# CMD: extract variable string from .txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have myfile.txt containing this:

```
line 1: keyword=string
line 2
line 3
```

I need to `echo` that **variable** `string` via *constant* `keyword`.

And this string I need is always in the end of the 1st line.

So far I have:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("myfile.txt") do (
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in ('findstr /i "keyword=" %%a') do (
echo %%b & goto 108
)
)

:108
```

But I guess that `findstr` syntax is completely wrong.

Please, help.

Comment: Try `for /f "usebackq tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ("myfile.txt") do echo %%b & goto 108` This should *tokenise* the first line read, assigning the string before the `=` (the `delims` (delimiters) character) to token 1 (the first-mentioned token number) to `%%a` (the *metavariable*). Because the second token "number" is `*` then the remainder of the line after the `=` is assigned to the next-alphabetical *metavariable*, `%%b`

Comment: In case you still want to use the findstr to find a specific line: `for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('findstr /i "keyword=" "myfile.txt"') do echo %%H`

Answer (score 0):

You can do rhis very simply as:

```
Echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
For /F "tokens=*" %%_ IN ('Type "c:\my\path\myfile.txt" ^| FIND /I "keyword="
  ) DO (
    SET "Tmp_Line=%%_"
    For /F "Tokens=* delims==" %%A in ('ECHO=!Tmp_Line:*keyword=!') DO (
      echo %%a
      GOTO :108
      Pause
    )
    GOTO :EOF
  )
Goto :EOF
```